# How to protect a random number seed?

Tags: random, passwords

I'm writing an application to protect passwords from key sniffers and screen retrievers.  I have the user type in an easy-to-remember keyword or phrase (i.e, "password123", "amazon.com", "gmail") and I use that string to create a longer and stronger password which is loaded into the clipboard.  I want the application to be completely anonymous, so I don't save any information.  To generate the passwords, I use a random number generator.  I need a way for the user to carry around their seed that isn't vulnerable to key sniffers or screen retrievers.  I'm thinking a hardware token like a YubiKey, but I would like something more easier and more mainstream.  I tried using behavioral biometrics, but I managed to replicate them with a program too easily.  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are suggesting is a more than vulnerable approach.

First of all, there are open source and proven-correct algorithms and applications for the problem you are targeting. In security questions it is never a good idea to go and develop applications for critical operations (and handling passwords is always a critical operation) on your own, especially reinventing the wheel is almost in every case an endeavor doomed to fail.

Your approach is problematic in several points:

- To be anonymous the app needs to copy/paste or in-place-generate the password needed for some action. You will have a hard time avoiding screen retrievers capture that if you do not do some magic on OS level.
- Using one(!) random seed to protect several passwords makes each of them weaker than it was before.
- Carrying this random seed on a usb key and freely plugging it into all kinds of computers that you cannot control is a problem as each of them may be potentially malicious. The random seed could be silently retrieved, altered or deleted.

To give you some things to get paranoid about, google e.g. blue pill and you will see that the real problems dwell on another machine layer than the application you are talking about.

Instead have a look at the following approaches:

- 2 factor authentication (2FA) against malicious software and hardware stealing your passwords on type-in. See e.g. Google Authenticator.
- Secure operating systems against such software entering your system and retrieving your passwords. See e.g. QubesOS
- Read-only drives with secure / anonymous OS for usage on foreign and potentially dangerous machines even for very critical tasks such as banking. See e.g. Tails OS on a dvd (not a usb key!)
- Virtual machines to capsule potentially malicious tasks. See e.g. VirtualBox
- Trustable password safes like KeyPassX

In a nutshell: You can write such an application but it will most likely not be practical nor secure nor by so usable. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I currently use PasswordSafe in combination with OATH/HMAC.  I was trying to come up with a way to keep my master password safe from key sniffers, since the HMAC only adds six numbers to the end of the password.  The virtual keyboard included in PasswordSafe is vulnerable to screen retrievers.  In my application, the password is never printed on the screen, it is simply loaded into the clipboard to be pasted into a password field.  The vulnerability of USB keys is why I was considering YubiKey and similar hardware tokens.

Comment: Screen retrievers are definitely a thing to be worried about. But if one is smart enough to write or even just use one of those they will also be prepared to simply read out the clipboard. This is usually routinely done in this kind of software anyway. The "official" solution to that would be 2FA or a rom os.

Comment: Is there any way to protect the clipboard?

Comment: Depends a bit, mostly on the os you are writing for. The simple way to go  is to frequently delete the c/b or to detect the successful pasting of your password to a field and then delete it from c/b. Sure this does not prevent other software from copying it in this critical time slot. If you are able to negotiate a handshake with the receiving software or form you could set up an encrypted channel (similar to https e.g.).